# Poetry 1.0.2 and Python 3.8 на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

На Ubuntu 18.04 есть встроенный пайтон версии 3.6.9.
Я решил в своём проекте использовать последнюю версию, и установил дополнительно python3.8.

Товарищи, вопросы такие:

1) Установил Poetry через get-poetry.py. При запуске poetry цепляет python2.7 и каждый раз выдает мне сообщение:

```
/home/user/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/subprocess32.py:149: RuntimeWarning: The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.
  "program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)
```

Получилось вылечить эту проблему, заменив в файле

```
/home/user/.poetry/bin/poetry

#!/usr/bin/env python
```

на

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Есть какие-нибудь другие варианты решения этой проблемы?

2) При попытке установить для poetry интерпретатор python3.8 получаю следующую ошибку:

```
user@Satellite:~/PycharmProjects/user_blog$ poetry env use python3.8
Creating virtualenv user-blog-esv86Tu3-py3.8 in /home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/venv/__init__.py", line 68, in create
    self._setup_pip(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/venv/__init__.py", line 289, in _setup_pip
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/user-blog-esv86Tu3-py3.8/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Using virtualenv: /home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/user-blog-esv86Tu3-py3.8
```

при этом poetry env info:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.8.1
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/user-blog-esv86Tu3-py3.8
Valid:          False

System
Platform: linux
OS:       posix
Python:   /usr
```

Виртуальное окружение создается с ошибкой и не работает.

Comment: @a_murz попробуйте создать виртуальное окружение командой python3 -m venv например в $HOME, поставить в это окружение poetry и прописать путь до директории bin окружения в $PATH. После чего перезапустить машину.